# AngularJS ng-grid pagination issue - Buttons are not disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, ng-grid

I have the following code,

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/CIjY45LGDUviCXVWONLQ?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <input type="text" ng-model="settings.filterOptions.filterText" />
   <div class="list" ng-grid="settings"></div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.result = [];
  $scope.all_data = [..............];
  $scope.totalServerItems = 0;
  $scope.selectedItems = [];
  $scope.pagingOptions = {
          currentPage : 1,
          pageSize : 10
          };
  $scope.filterOptions = {
          filterText: '',
          useExternalFilter : true
          };
  if(!$scope.settings){
      $scope.settings = {
          enableColumnResize : true,
          pagingOptions : $scope.pagingOptions,
          filterOptions : $scope.filterOptions,
          sortInfo: {fields: [], columns: [], directions: [] },
          jqueryUITheme : true,
          enablePaging : true,
          useExternalSorting : true,
          showFooter : true,
          virtualizationThreshold: 100
      };
  }

  $scope.settings.data = 'result';
  $scope.settings.totalServerItems = 'totalServerItems';
  $scope.settings.selectedItems = $scope.selectedItems;

  $scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function (new_value, old_value) {
      if($scope.filterOptions.filterText != ''){
        return false;
      }
      var pagedData = $scope.all_data.slice((new_value.currentPage - 1) * new_value.pageSize , new_value.currentPage * new_value.pageSize);
      $scope.result = pagedData;
      $scope.totalServerItems = $scope.all_data.length;
      if (!$scope.$$phase) {
          $scope.$apply();
      }
  }, true);

  $scope.$watch('filterOptions', function (new_value, old_value) {
      if(new_value){
          $scope.result = $filter('filter')($scope.all_data, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
          if (!$scope.$$phase) {
              $scope.$apply();
          }
      }
  }, true);
});
```

**Problem**

When I filter with some random keywords, the grid gets empty but the pagination buttons are not disabled, I can still click the remaining number of pages. Can someone explain me the problem?

---

**UPDATE**
I fixed it by making a very small change in the `filterOptions` watch. Which looks like,

**Demo** http://plnkr.co/edit/ULLg6AuTBprMXEcR7eXC?p=preview

**JS**

```
$scope.$watch('filterOptions', function (new_value, old_value) {
      if(new_value){
          $scope.result = $filter('filter')($scope.all_data, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
          $scope.totalServerItems = $scope.result.length; //This helped out to fix the issue
          if (!$scope.$$phase) {
              $scope.$apply();
          }
      }
  }, true);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's easy to use Directive.for example [example](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/12558/angularjs-and-datatables-icons-each-line/p1)  or http://jsfiddle.net/TNy3w/2/

Comment: FYI, I am not using jQuery datatable... It is angularjs ng grid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by making a very small change in the `filterOptions` watch. Which looks like,

**Demo** http://plnkr.co/edit/ULLg6AuTBprMXEcR7eXC?p=preview

**JS**

```
$scope.$watch('filterOptions', function (new_value, old_value) {
      if(new_value){
          $scope.result = $filter('filter')($scope.all_data, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
          $scope.totalServerItems = $scope.result.length; //This helped out to fix the issue
          if (!$scope.$$phase) {
              $scope.$apply();
          }
      }
  }, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i'm late.

I got this working by adding a modified footer template to the script:

```
    var ft= "<div ng-show=\"showFooter\" class=\"ngFooterPanel\" ng-class=\"{'ui-widget-content': jqueryUITheme, 

    ....

    "            <button class=\"ngPagerButton\" ng-click=\"pageForward()\" ng-disabled=\"cantPageForward()|| result.length < pagingOptions.pageSize\" title=\"{{i18n.ngPagerNextTitle}}\"><div class=\"ngPagerLastTriangle ngPagerNextTriangle\"></div></button>" +
    "            <button class=\"ngPagerButton\" ng-click=\"pageToLast()\" ng-disabled=\"cantPageToLast()|| result.length < pagingOptions.pageSize\" title=\"{{i18n.ngPagerLastTitle}}\"><div class=\"ngPagerLastTriangle\"><div class=\"ngPagerLastBar\"></div></div></button>" +

    ....
```

and assigning it to the grid with:

```
  $scope.settings = {
    ...
      footerTemplate:ft
  };
```

I'm about to leave for the weekend so i can't test this throughly, but i hope it helps anyhow.

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LR02lojMfo1DxbUAJIfo?p=preview) to play around with it.

Comment: I have updated my post with temporary fix. I am sure, there is no problem in in the ng-grid plugin, I am doing something wrong. Thanks for you comments.